# Change div to form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with text inside:

```
<div id="test">Some text here to edit</div>
```

When the users clicks on this it needs to change to:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Edit: <input type="text" name="tex" value="Some text here to edit"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How can I make it so when the user clicks on the text in the div, it will transform into an form/input box like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Demo

With HTML and jQuery (a JavaScript framework): http://jsfiddle.net/3qHst/1/.

## Additional info

jQuery doc: [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

## Code

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<div id="test">Some text here to edit</div>

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get" style="display: none;">
    <label for="comment">Edit:</label>
    <input type="text" id="comment" value="Some text here to edit"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('form').show();
});
```

Comment: This solution is correct, but my question was not clear.  I need it made in pure code.  I've made a new question for it.  Thanks.

Comment: wehen you say "pure code" do you mean you want the input generated by the jquery code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may be in luck, because there's a jquery plugin to do exactly that. There are actually a few, but I think this is the first one. The others were forks of this project if I'm not mistaken.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

It would be somewhat easy to do what you're asking manually, but the jeditable plugin actually connects to a web service that saves the info to a database, which may or may not be what you're looking for.

Let me work on a jsfiddle and see what I can do.

**EDIT**

I made this jsfiddle - it works on my local machine, but I can't get it to work on my browser in jsfiddle for some reason. But I've been having trouble with jsfiddle recently, I have no idea why.

Anyway, here's the link. Let me know if this doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/XXbgp/2/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id='form' name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
    <div id="test">Some text here to edit</div>
    <input type="text" name="tex" value="" class="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('#test').hide();
    $('#form').children('input').show();
    $('#form').children('input[name=tex]').val($('#test').html());
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
#test { cursor: pointer; }
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/melachel/ymw4Z/

Comment: Is there a jQuery 1.7.1 compatible version for this? Seems to only work for me with 1.7.2 on jsfiddle.

Comment: it works to me with jQuery 1.7.1 on jsfiddle, tested on both Chrome 19.0.1084.56 and Firefox 12.0 on MacOS X. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the html5 contentEditable attribute on the div, which would allow you to make changes to the div inline.

http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable